# DateTimePickerModal On Working on Android

Tags: android, react-native, use-state

I have used `react-native-modal-datetime-picker` to create a calendar view. I have created a state, `birthDate` to set my date using `onChange` function in `DateTimePickerModal`. The problem is the date is getting picked on IOS device but while picking the date in Android the state of `birthDate` is not changing and it is taking the value which is used while initializing the state that present Date.
Below is my code for the same:

```
const [isDatePickerVisible, setDatePickerVisibility] = useState(false);
const [birthDate, setBirthDate] = useState(new Date());
const showDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(true);
    chosenDate: ''
  };

  const hideDatePicker = (date) => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(false);
    chosenDate: moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
  };

  const handleConfirm = (date) => {
    console.warn("A date has been picked: ", date);
    console.log('Type of Date', typeof (date))
    hideDatePicker();
  };

const updateBday = () => {
    console.log("Date", birthDate)
    updateDoc(doc(db, 'users', user.uid), {
      dateOfBirth: birthDate
    }).then(() => {
      navigation.navigate('GenderPage')
    })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
      })
  };

return (
<View style={styles.inputView}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.textInput} onPress={showDatePicker}>
          <AntDesign name="calendar" size={30} color="black" style={styles.calendarIcon} />
          <DateTimePickerModal
            isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
            mode="date"
            onChange={(date) => setBirthDate(date)}
            onConfirm={handleConfirm}
            onCancel={hideDatePicker}
          />
          <Text style={styles.dateView}>
            {birthDate ? moment(birthDate).format('   MMMM DD, YYYY') : '-'}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
)
```

Anyone facing the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue where the state of my object was getting changed in IOS but not in Android. I was able to resolve the issue by setting the state of `birthDate` in `handleConfirm` function. You can write the function as below:

```
const handleConfirm = (date) => {
    console.log("A date has been picked: ", date);
    console.log('Type of Date', typeof (date))
    setBirthDate(date)
    hideDatePicker();
  };
```

Hope it helps.